# Facebook Graph Api for joined groups

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

In latest FB Graph apis, can we list all the pubic groups that we have joined?
In my app I need to list all the public groups that I have joined. If needed I need to save some details from some of the post from those public groups? Is there any permission issue for this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only list groups you manage, with the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/me/groups` endpoint.

To access the group feed, use the `/group-id/feed` endpoint.

Comment: But hot to get that group id of a particular group i have joined?

Comment: that´s a bit tricky, if the group got a vanity url already you can use the search api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search - but in general, you should only worry about groups you manage.